# How to get ALL google contacts data in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, google-contacts-api

I tried to get all  google contacts data in a datagridview, the Google developers documentation its not very useful. I use this code but only retrieves: Name, Email, Phone and Birthday. How can I retrieve ALL?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.Contacts
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml

Partial Public Class _Default
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Dim scope = New List(Of String)
    Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim rs As New RequestSettings("APP NAME", "EMAIL@gmail.com", "PASSWORD")
        'Application Name,Username,password
        Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(rs)
        'Request all contacts
        rs.AutoPaging = True
        'Allow autopaging
        Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.GetContacts()
        'Get all contacts
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim dr As DataRow
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        dt.Columns.Add("Phone")
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailHome")
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailWork")
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailOther")
        dt.Columns.Add("Birthday")
        dt.Columns.Add("Address")
       For Each exi As Contact In f.Entries
            dr = dt.NewRow()
            Dim n As Name = exi.Name
            dr(0) = n.FullName
            Dim homeemail As String = ""
            Dim workemail As String = ""
            Dim otheremail As String = ""
            Dim homephone As String = ""
            Dim workphone As String = ""
            Dim otherphone As String = ""
            Dim birth As String = ""
            Dim address As String = ""
            For Each ph As PhoneNumber In exi.Phonenumbers
                If ph.Other = True Then
                    If otherphone.Equals("") Then
                        otherphone += ph.Value
                    Else
                        otherphone += ","
                        otherphone += ph.Value
                    End If
                ElseIf ph.Home = True Then
                    If homephone.Equals("") Then
                        homephone += ph.Value
                    Else
                        homephone += ","
                        homephone += ph.Value

                    End If

                Else
                    If workphone.Equals("") Then
                        workphone += ph.Value
                    Else
                        workphone += ","
                        workphone += ph.Value

                    End If

                End If

                dr(1) = workphone

            Next
            For Each email As EMail In exi.Emails
                If email.Home = True Then
                    If homeemail.Equals("") Then
                        homeemail += email.Address
                    Else
                        homeemail += ","
                        homeemail += email.Address
                    End If
                End If
                If email.Work = True Then
                    If workemail.Equals("") Then
                        workemail += email.Address
                    Else
                        workemail += ","
                        workemail += email.Address
                    End If
                Else
                    If otheremail.Equals("") Then
                        otheremail += email.Address
                    Else
                        otheremail += ","
                        otheremail += email.Address
                    End If
                End If
                dr(2) = homeemail
                dr(3) = workemail
                dr(4) = otheremail
            Next
            Try
                birth = exi.ContactEntry.Birthday.ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                birth = ""
            End Try
            dr(5) = birth
            For Each wb As Website In exi.ContactEntry.Websites
                address = wb.ToString
                dr(6) = address
            Next

            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
```

Comment: can you share the google link for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example, and it is working fine (asp.net). Add the fields that you want.

First off, Add two textbox (txtgmailusername, txtpassword), one button (Button1) and a gridView (gridemails) and paste this code:

```
public DataSet GetGmailContacts(string p_name, string e_id, string psw)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
    dc1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc1.ColumnName = "emailid";
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
    dc2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc2.ColumnName = "name";
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(p_name, e_id, psw);
    rs.AutoPaging = true;
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
    Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
    {
        foreach (EMail email in t.Emails)
        {
            //DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            //dr1["emailid"] = email.Address.ToString();
            //dr1["name"] = email.XmlName.ToString();
            //dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
            //counter++;
        }
        Name nameContact = t.Name;
        DataRow drx = dt.NewRow();
        drx["emailid"] = t.PrimaryEmail.Address.ToString();
        drx["name"] = t.Title.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(drx);
        counter++;
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    Response.Write("Total:" + counter.ToString());
    return ds;
}

public void getcontacts()
{
    DataSet ds = GetGmailContacts("MyNetwork Web Application!", txtgmailusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
    gridemails.DataSource = ds;
    gridemails.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getcontacts();
    //create1contact("MyUsers", this.txtgmailusername.Text, this.txtpassword.Text);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Orlando, this is what Ive been looking for. Can you help me with another simple question?. How can I split this line:  Dim contact As Contact = cr.Retrieve(Of Contact)(contactURL)     Because it says: overload resolution error (error de resolucion de sobrecarga)

Comment: De nada Alan. What are you traying to do in that line?

Comment: Nevermind I put "New FeedQuery" before contactURL and it work. Thank you very much.